# Retrieve older call history on iPhone

Tags: iphone, call, history

When I look at the "Recents"-tab on my iPhone, I can see about 100 call entries. But when I delete a call an older call moves up. So, older calls must be stored somewhere. Is there a way to recover the call history without deleting calls?

Answer (score 0):

There are softwares such as [iMazing](https://imazing.com/) and [iMyPhone D](https://www.imyfone.com/ios-data-recovery).
I can confirm you that with the first one I managed to get 204 contacts until around 5 month earlier, so I bet that there is still a max number in the OS, I'm sure I'd have more calls, but at least it's something.